# My else is not working but doesn't show any error sign. If, elif is working perfectly. python is my code

Tags: python

```
print("Calculator for substraction, addition, multiplication and division")

sign=input("Enter a sign:")

num1=float(input("Enter a number:"))

num2=float(input("Enter a second number:"))

def wrong_sign():
    print("Sign entered is invalid please use one of those 1. - for substraction \n 2. + for addition \n 3. x or * for multiplication \n 4. / for devision")

if sign == "-":
    print(num1-num2)

elif sign == "+" :
    print(num1+num2)

elif sign == "/":
    print(num1/num2)

elif sign == "*" or "x":
    print(num1 * num2)

else: 
    wrong_sign
```

There are no code errors just when i try to type in an invalid sign as a user nothing comes up and the wrong_sign code doesn't show.

Comment: You mean `wrong_sign()`. Also note, `elif sign == "*" or "x"` needs to be `elif sign == "*" or sign == "x"` or something similar.

Comment: `elif sign == "*" or "x":` should be `elif sign == "*" or sign == "x":`.  Another option is: `elif sign in  ("*", "x"):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the round brackets to call a function:

```
else:
    wrong_sign()
```

Comment: Yeah just need to make sure you also fix your last elif. `elif sign == "*" or sign == "x"`

Answer (score 0):

you should change one of your elif statements:

```
elif sign == "*" or sign == "x":
```

Comment: I changed the answer. You should change one of your elif statements.

Answer (score 0):

In last line, You've to call `wrong_sign()` function:

```
else:
    wrong_sign()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your correct code

```
print("Calculator for substraction, addition, multiplication and division")

sign=input("Enter a sign:")

num1=float(input("Enter a number:"))

num2=float(input("Enter a second number:"))


def wrong_sign():
    print("Sign entered is invalid please use one of those 1. - for substraction \n 2. + for addition \n 3. x or * for multiplication \n 4. / for devision")

if sign == "-":
    print(num1-num2)

elif sign == "+" :
    print(num1+num2)

elif sign == "/":
    print(num1/num2)

elif sign == "*" or sign == "x":
    print(num1 * num2)

else: 
    wrong_sign()
```

**Output for invalid sign**

```
Calculator for substraction, addition, multiplication and division
Enter a sign:$
Enter a number:2
Enter a second number:3
Sign entered is invalid please use one of those 1. - for substraction 
 2. + for addition 
 3. x or * for multiplication 
 4. / for devision
​
```